# jQuery plugin - dynamic click handling on global selector

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, scope, global-variables

I am programming a jQuery plugin which loads a small widget (GET-method) from which later a click event should be fired.

Well the element selector is not in DOM when initializing the plugin. So how can I achieve a global storing of the selector to handle the click event?

I've kept the code short and simple for you to understand.

```
(function($) {
    var $template; // the global variable

    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        $(this).bind('click', function(e) {
            $.get('/template.html', function(data) {
                $('body').append(data);
                $template = $(data); // set global variable here
            }
        }

        // fire click event on global variable here, but $template is undefined
        $(document).on('click', $template.find('.button'), function() {
            // do something
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just define the event handler in the callback when the template is sure to be loaded already.

```
(function($) {
    var $template; // the global variable

    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        $(this).bind('click', function(e) {
            $.get('/template.html', function(data) {
                $('body').append(data);
                $template = $(data); // set global variable here
                // fire click event on global variable here, but $template is undefined
                $(document).on('click', $template.find('.button'), function() {
                // do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I've already thought about that, but isn't there another way so I can use the selecter later on? Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: If you really don't want to put the handler in that block, you can use a `Promise` to do the fetch, then use `.then()` to initialize the handler.